# Drawing simple graphics over video, Play video frame-by-frame in Surface by lockCanvas() using MediaCodec? Surface without attching to window?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-mediacodec, surface, live-wallpaper

I'm making a Live Wallpaper for Android API level 19+.
My wallpaper consists of two layers.

1. I want to play video on a background. It should to be
   transformable. I want to be able to change the scale and position of
   the video.
2. In the foreground I need to draw a simple graphics like
   сanvas.drawCircle().

#### My attempts:

I started with MediaPlayer. The code below can play a video on wallpaper, but it can’t to draw graphics over the video. OR it can draw graphics, but can't the video. As I understood it's because MediaPlayer completely locks the Canvas. I tried this by running MediaPlayer into the single Surface, in which I drawn animation of circle in the `draw()` method. And I received `BaseSurfaceHolder: Exception locking surface`.

**There is a global problem that limits me:**

Wallpaper is a Service, not an Activity. This is limited by the fact that we have only one Surface, which is created by the class `WallpaperService.Engine` *(I may be wrong)*. Also we can't use any View objects.

#### Desired wallpaper result:

1. Play background video (WebM preferred)
2. To have a possibility to transform video (scale, translate)
3. Draw simple foreground graphics

#### Questions

Now I have some ideas to implement this, but I don't know if it is possible:

1. Is there a possible way **to transform Surface's content**? (exactly Surface, not a SurfaceView)
2. Is it possible **to create an additional Surface** and then draw both Surfaces one above the other like a second layer? (maybe SurfaceFlinger does that?)
3. Is it possible to use **MediaCodec** (which I'll have to study) to decode video and draw it **frame-by-frame** in draw() method using lock/unlock canvas and draw simple graphics there?
4. Is it possible to have a **SurfaceView but don't attach it to window**? I tried it and got `"surface has been released" Exception`. How can I attach it in my case? As I understand it must to be attached to a window. But I don't have a window.

Now my code can only draw video OR draw graphics, and I'm almost sure that I need to replace the MediaPlayer for something else:

```
package com.android.grafika;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import java.io.IOException;

import static java.lang.Math.PI;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;


public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService{

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MyEngine();
    }


    class MyEngine extends WallpaperService.Engine implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{

        private MediaPlayer player = null;
        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        private Handler handler = new Handler();
        private boolean visible = false;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private int counter = 0;
        private int frameDelay = 30;
        private int rawVideoId = R.raw.mage_1sec;
        private Runnable drawFrame = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                draw();
                counter++;
                if (visible) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, frameDelay);
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
            this.holder = surfaceHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
            this.visible = visible;
            if (visible) {
                handler.post(drawFrame);
                //playerStart();    // uncomment it and comment the statement above to draw the video
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(drawFrame);
                //playerRelease();  // uncomment it and comment the statement above to draw the video
            }
        }

        private void draw() {
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
            //mediaDecoder.drawVideoFrame(canvas); // this is my imaginary statement
            canvas.drawCircle(600f, (float) cos( (double) counter /30f * PI) * 200f + 400f, 30f, paint); // simple animation
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

        /**
         * MediaPlayer implementation
         */
        private void playerRelease() {
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }

        private void playerStart() {
            try {
                player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.setSurface(holder.getSurface());
                player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + rawVideoId));
                player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                player.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            player.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I'll be glad to any help: references, samples, advices or libs. Maybe I'm not doing everything right and you can say it to me.

Thank you for any help!